# Laravel - message: "Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException"

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel-5.8 as backend. I have a Post Request as shown below:

```
    public function storeClientQuote(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userFirstName = Auth::user()->first_name;
        $userLastName = Auth::user()->last_name;
        $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;

        $dashboardowner = Client::join("users","users.client_id","=","clients.client_id")
                            ->select("clients.client_name", "users.id", "users.first_name", "clients.address1", "clients.address2")
                            ->where('users.id', $user->id) 
                            ->get();  

        if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Add Quote'))
            return response()->json([ "message" => 'User do not have permission'], 401);
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|max:14',
          //  'business_name' => 'string',
            'truck_type' => 'required',
            'truck_required' => 'required',
            'quote_origin' => 'required',
            'quote_destination' => 'required',
            'commodity' => 'required',  
            'loading_date' => 'date|required' 
        ]);
        $clientquote = new ClientQuote;
        $clientquote->first_name= $userFirstName;
        $clientquote->last_name=$userLastName;
        $clientquote->email=$userEmail;
        $clientquote->phone=$request->get('phone');
        $clientquote->business_name= $dashboardowner[0]->client_name;
        $clientquote->address= $dashboardowner[0]->address1 . " " . $dashboardowner[0]->address2;
        $clientquote->truck_type=$request->get('truck_type');
        $clientquote->truck_required=$request->get('truck_required');
        $clientquote->quote_origin=$request->get('quote_origin');
        $clientquote->quote_destination=$request->get('quote_destination');
        $clientquote->commodity=$request->get('commodity');
        $loading_date=date_create($request->get('loading_date'));
        $format = date_format($loading_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $clientquote->loading_date = $format;
        $clientquote->save();


        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Quote Successfully Sent!'
        ], 201);
    }
```

When I tried to debug, I found that the error started from:

> $userFirstName = Auth::user()->first_name;

with the messages:

> message: "Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException"

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means Auth::user() is returning null which usually occurs if there's no logged in user. First check if user is logged in with `Auth::check()` before trying to access properties of `Auth::user()`

If that controller method is only meant or logged in user, you can set Auth Middleware on the route calling the controller method.

And if the entire controller is supposed to be accessible to only logged in user, set the Auth Middleware in the controller construct method.

That way, you're always sure the logged in user is accessible I.e Auth::user() will be an object

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$user = auth()->user();
$userFirstName = $user->first_name;
```

Comment: This will return the same error as user is experiencing. If there's no logged-in user, `auth()->user()` will return null just as \Auth::user()`

Comment: You are right, i assumed that the requesting user is logged-in.